# Avoid Re-initialization of Critical Section

Tags: windows, winapi, critical-section

I have a dll that creates a global critical section, initializes and use it.

Now a third party application is using / loading the dll more than once which leads to a heap corruption.

The [appverifier](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457063.aspx) warns me with a

-->
VERIFIER STOP 00000211: pid 0x1470: Critical section is already initialized. 
<--

Using a global flag to check if the critical section object is already initialized doesn't help, any ideas on accomplishing the same ?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Initialize Critical Section only once for a process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724560/initialize-critical-section-only-once-for-a-process)

Answer (score 0):

> Now a third party application is using / loading the dll more than once

Windows does not reload the same DLL multiple times. Where *same* means same path. If the 3rd party app is loading from different locations, that is the problem.

Comment: Windows can relaod the same DLL multiple times.  DLLs are reference counted.  You also have calls for process and thread start stop.  If the loading app frees the library and loads it again this is entirely possible.  It indicates no cleanup code on the critical section when the dll is freed.

Comment: The DLL will not be reloaded with another LoadLibrary call, the reference will be incremented, but DllMain will *not* be called.

Answer (score 0):

May be using the "setAtom" and "getAtom" APIs help? I know they are a bit "old-school" but you can never know.